# .htaccess with virtual hosting zend framework 1 ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, virtual-hosts

I have setup an Ubuntu server that has virtual hosting, in the folder `:/var/www/vhosts/dev.blla.com/httpdocs/src` is the web application built with zend framework 1.
The problem is that I have an .htaccess file that looks like below:

```
<VirtualHost dev.blla.com:80>
    ServerName   dev.blla.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/dev.blla.com/httpdocs

    RewriteEngine off

    <Location />
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The .htacess file is located in `/var/www/vhosts/dev.blla.com/httpdocs`, the web shows `500 Internal Server Error` what am I doing wrong?

In an error log I have this line: `/var/www/vhosts/dev.blla.com/httpdocs/.htaccess: <VirtualHost not allowed here, referer: http://dev.blla.com/`

vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:7080>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Check to make sure you have enabled the Rewrite module for apache

Comment: It is enabled checked by a2enmod rewrite which returned Module rewrite already enabled

Comment: Try removing the line that says RewriteEngine Off, just to make sure.  Otherwise try a simpler rewrite.  Something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]`

Comment: I removed RewriteEngine Off same result.
Where should i put the following: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]

Comment: Yeah we need a bit more detail on your setup.  If you get a Nginx and apache errors you may be using a proxying service or specialized setup

Comment: Well i just stopped nginx in plesk, and the main page is showing up but all the other pages are showing 404 not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vhost file should look like this. Don't use `location` directive and especially to root `/`. You should be using `Directory`.

```
<VirtualHost dev.blla.com:80>
    ServerName   dev.blla.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/dev.blla.com/httpdocs

    <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/dev.blla.com/httpdocs">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

These are the only context `RewriteEngine` will work. `Location` is not one of them. Restart apache after changes.

```
server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine

**Edit:** Apparently you have this in your .htaccess file. That will not work. This is supposed to be your vhost file as I mentioned above. The only thing allowed in .htaccess is this alone. VirtualHost and Directory can **not** be used in .htaccess.

```
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This also might help you.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: I did all of the above but I still get the 500 Internal server error, I also checked an error_log i get this error /var/www/vhosts/dev.blla.com/httpdocs/.htaccess: <VirtualHost not allowed here, referer: http://dev.blla.com/

Comment: Wait is this inside your .htaccess file? This should be your **virtual host** file.

Comment: yes its inside the .htaccess file, where should I put it ?

Comment: where is the vhost file ?

Comment: I changed that, and restarted apache service now the landing page is working but other pages are not I get:Not Found

The requested document was not found on this server.

Comment: What do you have in your vhost file now?

Comment: I added my vhost file

Comment: You need to add `AllowOverride All` and `RewriteEngine On` in that order above your rules.

Comment: Dude are you using Apache or nginx? This is way beyond the problem you were having.

Comment: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/server.conf:6
AH00526: Syntax error on line 23 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
AllowOverride not allowed here
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: the problem escalated quickly

Comment: Look at my original answer. All off that including allow override needs to be in a **directory** tag just like I have it. If you can't get it after that, you need to get with your host. I can't walk you through a plesk configuration. This is a bit beyond the scope and Plesk takes over the server and controls everything on the box including Apache and has it's own way and conf files for doing things.